# React Admin "Invalid Token Specified" issues

Tags: react-admin

https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Authorization.html

Hi, I was follow this AUTH_GET_PERMISSIONS to do the permissions but it come out this error when I want to login:

It returned the message "Invalid Token Specified" error message.

[image]

This is the code for making the errors:

[image]

is it related with this code?:

```
const httpClient = (url, options = {}) => {

   if (!options.headers) {

      options.headers = new Headers({ Accept: 'application/json' });

   }

   const token = localStorage.getItem('token');

   options.headers.set('Authorization', `Bearer ${token}`);

   return fetchUtils.fetchJson(url, options);

}
```

The expected result:

It will login to the page & with the permissions to display the menu items based on the logged in users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your response you have `access_token: 'token_value'` as property name, but then in code you are destructing the function argument with `.then(( {token} ))...` as property name. So the value is undefined.

Comment: Yeah, I found this problem ady but now the problem is how to find the data of the logged in users, do you have any suggestions? Thank you.

Comment: you should retrieve current logged in user data with your `/login` response and save it to localStorage just like you do it with the 'role'

Comment: thank you, I pass through the username and it was able to retrieve the user data in react-admin. But this one I using JWT web token, it only returned username and password value, how to get the id or role permission from it? I have asked question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58409898/may-i-know-how-to-get-the-logged-in-user-id-in-react-admin , can you help? Thank you.